# how key exchanging happen in RSA for decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I want to implement the RSA encrypt/decrypt method in cipher in java in a code that does some treatment or changing to any data it receives and then sends it again, so I want this code to be able to:
- when it receives data, encrypt that data with RSA, I think this is easy, I saw many examples it generates a KeyPair and gets the public key then use the cipher to encrypt.
- when it receives data encrypted by RSA as i mentioned in decryption this is where I have a problem.. in all the examples I saw, it uses the private key generated in the encryption part to decrypt in cipher, but how can I do that if the two parties are separate?! how can the party how decrypt know the private key generated from the part how encrypt the data!

here is some code example I saw: 
https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/java-asymmetric-encryption-decryption-example-with-rsa.html

Answer (score 1):

> how can I do that if the two parties are separate?! how can the party how decrypt know the private key generated from the part how encrypt the data

The sender needs to know the public key of the recepient upfront. The recepient needs to generate its keypair and provide the public key to the sender to encrypt data. The sender must as well make sure the public key is really from the intended recepient (that's why we use certificates)

If you see generating a keypair by an encrypting party, this is done only as an example to have a public key.

Comment: so only the recipient generates a keypair ( then send the public key), and the sender does not generate keys? and the public key can be sent to the sender in an unsecured way I mean can anyone know the public key or it has to be kept secret, from what I can tell no ^^

Comment: @feiz public key is.. public. In TLS (https) every server makes its public key known. Indeed the public key doesn't need to be kept secret.